# Trouble getting FTP login to work in IIS6

Tags: security, iis-6, ftp, login

I'm trying to setup an FTP site for one of my clients to retrieve files from my organization using IIS6. I've created the FTP site, have set to not isolate users (not necessary as FTP will be read only with authentication).

Here's the problem. The FTP is to be password protected, so I turned of anonymous access on the FTP site. I then created a `ftpuser` account on the machine, and gave it read and browse directory permissions on the ftp's root directory. However, when I go to test the `ftpuser` login, I get a `530 "ftpuser cannot login"` error. However, if I browse to the same directory over HTTP (anonymous access turned off as well) and enter the `ftpuser` login info, I can download files and browse directories successfully. Why is the `ftpuser` working over HTTP but not FTP? Shouldn't I be able to login over FTP with the ftpuser login information I just created?

Answer (score 1):

FTP status code 530 is definitely related to a username\password error. Have you tried authenticating to the ftp site as:

machinename\ftpuser
password